Analytics is disabled. Event not logged - Ionic Cordova firebasex
I have invested so much time trying to integrate firebase analytics with my app.
first I discovered that google analytics is deprecated and I should use firebase analytics. so I decided to go with firebasex cordova plugin.
I have faced some issues with build and extra, but I finally managed to get it build.
When I try to apply the code for tracking screen it won't show in firebase dashboard.
I tried to enable debug mode using -FIRDebugEnabled but I get a very weird error while I am trying to log any event:
10.24.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS024000] Debug mode is on
10.24.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.10.24.0 started
10.24.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023013] Analytics collection disabled
10.24.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023049] Analytics is disabled. Event not logged

I tried to add code of configure and setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled both manually in iOS AppDelegate.m file [FIRAnalytics setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:YES] and using the firebasex plugin FirebasePlugin.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
I tried also to change values in GoogleService-Info.plist to be booleans or strings
without hope.
Can you help me, please?
Thanks in Advance.

I examined every line of code, every log, until I realized that, the previous developers were setting this brilliant overriding rule in the huge cordova config.xml file.
<config-file parent="FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED" target="*-Info.plist">
  <string>YES</string>
</config-file> 

Thanks so much StackOverflow <3
